# Repeated cross-sectional difference-in-difference with panel data on each of the 4 DiD-groups (pre/post treated/control)

Tags: panel-data, difference-in-difference

I am trying to estimate the effect of a university teaching reform on the wage of its graduates. I have panel data from 2003-2017 on all university students in the same country. The university under consideration started implementing the reform in 2009, and the reform can be assummed to have no effect on graduates from 2007, 2008 and 2009, and to have an effect on graduates from 2012, 2013 and 2014. I don't consider graduates from 2010 and 2011 in my analysis since their treatment status is unclear.

My data looks something like this (in the statistical software Stata):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte(id treated university year degree degreeyear male) int(wage wage1 wage2 wage3 wage4)
1 . 1  6 0  . 1    0    .    .    .    .
1 . 1  7 0  . 1    0    .    .    .    .
1 0 1  8 1  8 1    0    .    .    .    .
1 0 .  9 1  8 1 2000 2000    .    .    .
1 0 . 10 1  8 1 3000    . 3000    .    .
1 0 . 11 1  8 1 3500    .    . 3500    .
1 0 . 12 1  8 1 4000    .    .    . 4000
1 0 . 13 1  8 1 4000    .    .    .    .
1 0 . 14 1  8 1 5000    .    .    .    .
1 0 . 15 1  8 1 5000    .    .    .    .
1 0 . 16 1  8 1 5000    .    .    .    .
1 0 . 17 1  8 1 5000    .    .    .    .
2 . 2  6 0  . 0    0    .    .    .    .
2 0 2  7 1  . 0    0    .    .    .    .
2 0 .  8 1  . 0 2200 2200    .    .    .
2 0 .  9 1  . 0 2300    . 2300    .    .
2 0 . 10 1  . 0 2400    .    . 2400    .
2 0 . 11 1 11 0 2500    .    .    . 2500
2 0 . 12 1 11 0 2600    .    .    .    .
2 0 . 13 1 11 0 2700    .    .    .    .
2 0 . 14 1 11 0 2800    .    .    .    .
2 0 . 15 1 11 0 2900    .    .    .    .
2 0 . 16 1 11 0 3000    .    .    .    .
2 0 . 17 1 11 0 3000    .    .    .    .
3 . .  6 0  . 1    0    .    .    .    .
3 . .  7 0  . 1    0    .    .    .    .
3 . .  8 0  . 1    0    .    .    .    .
3 . .  9 0  . 1    0    .    .    .    .
3 . 1 10 0  . 1    0    .    .    .    .
3 . 1 11 0  . 1    0    .    .    .    .
3 . 1 12 0  . 1    0    .    .    .    .
3 1 1 13 1 13 1    0    .    .    .    .
3 1 . 14 1 13 1 4000 4000    .    .    .
3 1 . 15 1 13 1 4200    . 4200    .    .
3 1 . 16 1 13 1 4400    .    . 4400    .
3 1 . 17 1 13 1 4600    .    .    . 4600
4 . .  6 0  . 0 4800    .    .    .    .
4 . .  7 0  . 0    0    .    .    .    .
4 . .  8 0  . 0    0    .    .    .    .
4 . .  9 0  . 0    0    .    .    .    .
4 . 1 10 0  . 0    0    .    .    .    .
4 . 1 11 0  . 0    0    .    .    .    .
4 . 1 12 0  . 0    0    .    .    .    .
4 . 1 13 0  . 0    0    .    .    .    .
4 0 1 14 1 14 0 3800    .    .    .    .
4 0 . 15 1 14 0 4100    .    .    .    .
4 0 . 16 1 14 0 4400    .    .    .    .
4 0 . 17 1 14 0 4700    .    .    .    .
end
```

In the difference in difference terminology I have data on four groups:

- Pre-treatment treated: Graduates from the university which implemented the reform before the reform was implemented. In my data: university 1, from the years 2007-2009.
- Pre-treatment control: Graduates from universities which did not implement the reform before the reform was implemented. For the sake of simplicity I just show one other university in the dataexample below and call that university 2.
- Post-treatment treated: Graduates from university 1 after reform implementation (years 2012-2014)
- Post-treatment control: Graduates from university 2 after reform implementation (years 2012-2014)

I plan on using propensity score matching difference in difference. My data is panel data, but in the sense that the pre-treatment and post-treatment individuals are different, the data is included in the DiD-analysis as repeated cross-sectional. However, within each of the four groups I have panel data on the course of their wage development after their graduation.

So simply having the wage e.g. four years after graduation (wage4) as the outcome variable:

```
 didregress (wage4) (treated), group(university) time(year)
```

…would not utilize all the information I have in my dataset. I have a sense that there is a better way to perform the analysis than suggested in my code above, i.e., better in the sense of utilizing all the available information, but I don't know how. So can anyone inform me on how I can take advantage of the fact that I have panel data on each of the four groups even though the pre- and post-treatment groups are different individuals?

To be transparent I should add, that I asked the question in statalist.org as well, but did not recieve an answer: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1678391-repeated-cross-sectional-difference-in-difference-with-panel-data-on-each-of-the-4-did-groups-pre-post-treated-control

Comment: Welcome. You really shouldn’t cross-post. Please note that your question was posted on Statalist a few days ago. You should give time for contributors to craft a response. While your question is nicely written, it requires a response from someone well-versed in those methods. Give it time :)

Comment: Hi Thomas, I simply assumed that cross-posting was allowed here since it is on Statalist and since I did not find it stated that it was not allowed, when reading the tips on how to post questions on this forum. For anyone interested this is the link to my post on Statalist: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1678391-repeated-cross-sectional-difference-in-difference-with-panel-data-on-each-of-the-4-did-groups-pre-post-treated-control.